# When i tilt head other parts of the body move as well (Animation, Rigging)

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

My rig actually works good, except for one part and I dont understand why.

Her jacket moves, when i tilt the head. I dont know how to fix it. The method i used to join rig with body is selecting mesh and rig and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> and click on *Automatic Weight*

Here are the pics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: Things like that always happen when you use `Automatic Weights`. The bone that moves the head has influence on the jacket, you can fix it with weight painting.

Comment: does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/250376/42221) help?