# Rigging - How do you preserve the belly volume of a chubby character?

Tags: rigging

I am facing an unusual problem while rigging an obese/fat character. Please find the screenshots (here the term ‘obese’ is used to point out that the issue is only arising for this kind of character shape only and don’t consider this otherwise please).

When the character is seated, its belly portion is getting into its body. I did plenty of rigging with many other normal characters, however, did not find this kind of unusual issue.

I am also providing a google drive link to the Blend file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LH5WHLuImztqtofeSi2AK7oXZXncrwuq/view?usp=sharing

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

For this big guy, I would **add an extra bone that preserves the volume of his impressive belly.**

This works in a similar way to the chest bones. You have probably removed these bones but in fact, I would restore them so that this male character can also take a deep breath, stick out his chest and pull in his belly to impress women. (It's a bit hard to do this with only the belly bone).

[image: animation - pull in the belly]
<sup>Scale and move the new belly bone to control the abdominal fat.</sup>

**How to Add the Belly Bone to the Metarig**

Just copy the second spine bone (*spine.001*), rotate it and align it to the belly. Make sure it's on the bone layer that you want **(1)** and the parent relationship is correct **(2)**. You need to be in *Edit* mode to change this setting.

In *Pose* mode, make sure you select the *Rigify Type* `basic.super_copy` **(3)** and, last but not least, use the *Options* of it to generate a control bone for it **(4)**. Then re-generate the animation rig with the Rigify button.

[image: customization of the metarig]
<sup>Customization of the Metarig</sup>

The control bone for the belly (yellow circle) might be hidden inside the character. In this case, you can adjust the *Viewport Display > Translation Y* value of this bone to move it outside.

[image: adjusting the position of the control bone]
<sup>Adjusting the position of the control bone</sup>

**How to Fix the Hole in Crotch Area**

The shirt and the pants of this character are loose mesh parts and not connected. The calculation of the *Automatic Weights* does not work very well in this case. When the character sits down, a large hole opens in the crotch area.

To fix this, I've duplicated the model, remeshed it, and bound the dummy to the rig with *Automatic Weights*. Finally, I've transferred the weights back to the original model. For details, have a look at this question & answer: [Armature with automatic weights using Rigify failed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251539/107598)

Comment: You are rocks. Your suggestion works great. Kindly, advise me a little further. If such issue of belly is happened at the butt area, then what bone is to be used in butt portion, in place of spine.001 that was used for belly portion?

Comment: Hi, glad it works for you. Sorry. I've missed the question. For a big butt, you could add two additional bones, one for each buttock. Honestly, I have never had a character that had such a big butt *:D* But I probably would duplicate the *Pelvis* bones. It doesn't matter if you add a new bone or duplicate an existing bone. Just make sure to name it properly and that it has the correct parent-child relationship.